# How to classify with enum

Tags: java, data-structures, enums

I use enum to indicate a type and subtype.

```
enum Type {

    TYPE1(1),

    TYPE2(2),
    ...

    private int constant;

    Type(int constant) {
        this.constant = constant;
    }
}

enum SubType {

    SUBTYPE1(1),

    SUBTYPE2(2),

    SUBTYPE3(3),
    ...

    private int constant;

    SubType(int constant) {
        this.constant = constant;
    }
}
```

Each type has a different subtype.

For example TYPE1 has subtypes SUBTYPE1 and SUBTYPE2, TYPE2 has subtypes SUBTYPE2 and SUBTYPE3.

What structure should I use to represent this relationship?
I thought of using map. e.g `Map<Type, List<SubType>>`

Is there any other way?

Comment: Looks fine to me as long as `Type#constant` is `final`. You can also consider `EnumMap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the Type and Subtype infrastructure is constant, you could always attach a list of Subtypes to the Type enum.

```
enum Type {

    TYPE1(1, Arrays.asList(SubType.SUBTYPE1, SubType.SUBTYPE2)),

    TYPE2(2, Arrays.asList(SubType.SUBTYPE3),
    ...

    private int constant;
    public final List<SubType> subtypes;

    Type(int constant, List<SubType> subtypes) {
        this.constant = constant;
        this.subtypes = subtypes;
    }
}

enum SubType {

    SUBTYPE1(1),

    SUBTYPE2(2),

    SUBTYPE3(3),
    ...

    private int constant;

    SubType(int constant) {
        this.constant = constant;
    }
}
```

That might provide a more elegant way to access the subtypes of a Type.

As a side note, it's a good idea to use something like Arrays.asList() to define these mappings to ensure that the 'subtypes' list is immutable.

Comment: I would prefer to have take in `SubType... subTypes` in constructor and move the `Arrays.asList()` into the constructor.

Comment: That would certainly save on some duplication. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to extend your parent enums something like this:

```
public interface Type1{
    enum SubType1 implements Type1 {
    }
    enum SubType2 implements Type1{
    }
}

public interface Type2{
    enum SubType1 implements Type2 {
    }
    enum SubType2 implements Type2{
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options here:

1. you could use a map as you say. Ideally this would be `EnumMap<Type,List<Subtype>>` to take advantage of the efficiencies of `EnumMap`.
2. explicitly make retrieving subtypes a method of the types. That would mean adding a method (e.g. `Stream<Subtype> getSubtypes()`) to the enum which is overriden for each type.
3. Store the 'owner' type with the subtype.

   enum Subtype {
       SUBTYPE1(TYPE1), SUBTYPE2(TYPE1), SUBTYPE3(TYPE2)...

   ```
   private final Type parent;

   public static Stream<Subtype> getSubtypes(Type type) {
       return Arrays.stream(values()).filter(st -> st.parent.equals(type));
   }

   private Subtype(Type parent) {
       this.parent = parent;
   }
   ```

   }